# Interesting output using variables with NSLog() in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, variables, double, nslog, arithmetic-expressions

The following code:

```
int N = 100;
double total_time = 100;
double dt = total_time/N;
NSLog(@"Answer: %d", dt);
```

gives an interesting output: 5766 instead of 1.

Only in the case of adding

```
NSLog(@"Answer: %f", dt);
```

outputs the right answer. However, I would like to output "double" value instead of "float". What's wrong with my expectations and syntax?

Comment: You should already know basic C if you are attempting Objective-C, and one of the things you should know is the simple `printf` format scheme (as well as the difference between an integer and a float value).

Comment: Do you mean that I shouldn't ask the questions about Objective-C if I do not know basic C so good? How do you define what is basic and what is not? For me, some questions look basic, for others - not.

Comment: If you don't know, eg, how to use `printf` to print floating point values, that's a good sign that you're not familiar enough with C to be starting into Objective-C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%d` means "decimal representation of int", not "double".

You always output a double value using `%f`, because `NSLog()` has an open arg list. In such a case, all floating point numbers are passed as doubles. So you should read `%f` as "floating point number" not `float`.

Comment: Now, I see. But why the value of "5766"is chosen?

Comment: The "5766" isn't an arbitrarily chosen value, but rather its what the bytes represent when interpreted as a signed 32bit integer which is what %d is specified to do.

Answer (score 1):

%d and %i are the same thing, both decimal integer formats.